# Excel VBA check if clipboard is empty

Tags: vba, clipboard

I wrote a vba script to insert a certain amount of new rows in an excel sheet.
The code does his job, except when the clipboard isn't empty.

Is there any script available to clear the clipboard before executing this script?

Thanks!

Code without the clipboard check included below.

```
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Worksheet A" Then
    MsgBox "This macro only works in worksheet A"
Else
    Dim Rng As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    R = Selection.Row + 1

    Rng = InputBox("Amount of rows?")
    For k = 1 To Rng
        Rows(R).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you run your insert turn off `Application.CutCopyMode`:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "Worksheet A" Then
    MsgBox "This macro only works in worksheet A"
Else
    Dim Rng As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim R As Long

    R = Selection.Row + 1

    Rng = InputBox("Amount of rows?")
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    For k = 1 To Rng
        Rows(R).Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Next
End If
```